# Paypal Classic API, I get errors with authentication

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

This is my code, the credentials are correct, why do I get Authentication Failed? It is probably the headers but I can't figure out which.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "--",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "--,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "--",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" => "APP-80W284485P519543T",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NVP",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS" => "--",
    "Accept" => "application/json",
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/ConvertCurrency");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&
baseAmountList.currency(0).code=USD&
baseAmountList.currency(0).amount=1&
baseAmountList.currency(1).code=EUR&
baseAmountList.currency(1).amount=1&
baseAmountList.currency(2).code=SEK&
baseAmountList.currency(2).amount=1&
convertToCurrencyList.currencyCode=USD");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

In return I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-ID: 144ee8af-72d0-a486-d657-e4f2fffe5f49!AdaptivePayments!10.72.109.101![]
X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.0.0
X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-NAME: {http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap}AdaptivePayments
X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: XML
X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: ConvertCurrency
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-PAYPAL-ERROR-RESPONSE: TRUE
X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL: NONE
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
DC: origin1-svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
Date: Sun, 23 Mar 2014 10:44:48 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1395571488549095; path=/; expires=Tue, 15-Mar-44 10:44:48 GMT
Set-Cookie: DC=origin1-svcs.sandbox.paypal.com; secure

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap"><responseEnvelope><timestamp>2014-03-23T03:44:48.571-07:00</timestamp><ack>Failure</ack><correlationId>95445f07b579b</correlationId><build>10175386</build></responseEnvelope><error><errorId>520003</errorId><domain>PLATFORM</domain><subdomain>Application</subdomain><severity>Error</severity><category>Application</category><message>Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.</message></error></ns3:FaultMessage>
```

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the exact response returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the sandbox shared `X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID` which is correct for sandbox, but will not work in live. There you'd need your own application's ID.

My example also includes the header `"X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION": "1.0.0"`.